# Intercepting mouse events in windows

Tags: windows, mouse, routines

Well the title seems pretty clear about what I want to do.
More precisely: I want to create a program (c++ or java is preferred) that manipulates the mouse in two ways, like: changing its position and doing clicks.
I was thinking about using allegro (it has mouse routines to manipulate the things cited above) or sdl(which I don't know if has that kind of routine). I tried with allegro nsuccessfully. My problem here was that I couldn`t virtually "do" clicks. I also couldn't redirect the stuff changed by my program to some other window.

Any tips?

Comment: Use the SendInput() winapi function.

Comment: But how? What about the case where the program has to act outside of the window?

Comment: You did not specify that you needed this to work on minimized applications. Are you targetting a game? If so, it probably has protections against this sort of thing.

Comment: actually is a bot. I want to create a simple bot that makes the mouse click in intervals of a given time in a specified position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to try automating other applications on Windows...

At the simplest level, one can use `PostMessage` to post keyboard and mouse messages to another application's windows. This has the advantage that it *could* work even if the other application is minimized. Unfortunately, this approach skips the majority of the input processing logic so applications that directly access key state using `GetAsyncKeyState` will not see (for example) the control key being 'down' no matter how many `WM_KEYDOWN, vk=VK_CONTROL` messages you send.

As Hans Passant commented, `SendImput` places input events in a lower level input event queue, and so can fully simulate modifier keys. These input events are not posted to windows however, so to get the input events delivered successfully the normal windows rules of activation and focus need to be followed. That said, this is the approach used by most testing-automation software (and is why most testing automation software requires the application being tested be the active application).

The last of the automation methods Ill mention - and sadly the least likley to work - is the `Microsoft UI Automation` framework. This framework is intended to allow applications to be used by disabled and/or special needs users. Sadly - very few software providers bother to implement this API in their products.